# delete item from listbox on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am trying to delete item from listbox. i am using python2.7. when i am using remove it shows error.the same is for delete also

```
import tkinter
window=Tk()
ncbox = Tkinter.Listbox(window, width=14, height=7,fg="blue",font=("Helvetica", 20))
ncbox.grid(row=2, column=2,columnspan=4,sticky=NW)
yscroll = Tkinter.Scrollbar(command=ncbox.yview, orient=Tkinter.VERTICAL)
yscroll.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky=Tkinter.N+Tkinter.S)
ncbox.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
msg1='abc'
msg2='xyz'
gap='    '
ncbox.insert(Tkinter.END, msg1+gap+msg2)
ncbox.delete(msg1+gap+msg2)
if msg3+gap+msg4 in ncbox:
        print 'found'
window.mainloop()
```

How i could delete data? when i want to search it says that in is not a command for listbox. how could i change the color of every inserted text?

Comment: what is the error? Are you asking about deleting something, or changing the color? Those are two different things. Have you read the documentation on the listbox? Are you aware that the delete method takes an index, not the string representation of the item you want to delete?

Comment: i want both. please provide me a simple example.

Comment: ncbox.delete(ncbox.index(msg1+gap+msg2)) error is bad list box index"abc    xyz": must be active,end,anchor.@x,y  how i can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly what the problem is: you are giving it a bad index. The documentation for the delete method says you have to give an index. The documentation for the listbox widget describes what is a valid index -- a number, and a few special strings.

You need to tell the delete method which item *number* you want to delete.